# How to pass params query string in django GET request?

Tags: python, django, api, url

My path:

```
    path('<str:link>/', ListUserSearchView.as_view()),
```

My View:

```
class ListUserSearchView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, link):
        url = "baseurl"
        querystring = {"track_url": f'{link}'}
        headers = {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "apikey",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "apihost"
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        data = response.text

        return Response(data)
```

I would like to pass the link from params but this does not work, any help ?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes , 404, not found !

Comment: when hard code the link the api works so I just need to get it from the params